# Plot all dictionary points on a scatter plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dictionary which has clusters and each cluster contains different labels

```
Dictonary look like this
demo_dict = {0: [b'3.0',b'3.0', b'3.0', b'5.0',b'5.0',b'5.0', b'6.0', b'6.0'],
 1: [b'2.0', b'2.0', b'3.0', b'7.0',b'7.0'],
 2: [b'1.0', b'4.0', b'8.0', b'7.0',b'7.0']}
```

To draw a required plot, am using the following code

```
comp = demo_dict
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(comp, orient='index')
df.index.rename('Clusters', inplace=True)

stacked = df.stack().reset_index()
stacked.rename(columns={'level_1': 'Lable', 0: 'Labels'}, inplace=True)

sns.scatterplot(data=stacked, x='Clusters', y='Labels')
plt.show()
```

But the thing is, the above code is not drawing all the points, it just mentioned which clusters  contains which labels,but i want to have all the points of every cluster on visual.

[image]

Is, there something am missing in this code to generate all the points
Note: I have also tried with stripplot and swarmplot

Comment: You could try the approaches of [How to make jitterplot on matplolib python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229586/how-to-make-jitterplot-on-matplolib-python) to add jitter to the points after they have been drawn by `sns.scatterplot`. It all depends on how many points fall together and what exactly you want to show. It might be needed to use a smaller dot size or applying some alpha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `groupby` you can group using two columns. The counts can then be displayed via a heatmap:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

demo_dict = {}
for i in range(40):
    demo_dict[i] = np.random.choice([b'1.0', b'2.0', b'3.0', b'4.0', b'5.0', b'6.0', b'7.0', b'8.0'],
                                    np.random.randint(10, 30))
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(demo_dict, orient='index')
df.index.rename('Clusters', inplace=True)

stacked = df.stack().reset_index()
stacked.rename(columns={'level_1': 'Lable', 0: 'Labels'}, inplace=True)

grouped = stacked.groupby(['Labels', 'Clusters']).agg('count').unstack()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 4))
ax = sns.heatmap(data=grouped, annot=True, cmap='rocket_r', cbar_kws={'pad': 0.01})
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelrotation=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap of groupby counts]

An alternative is to show the counts as sizes in a scatterplot

```py
grouped = stacked.groupby(['Labels', 'Clusters']).agg('count').reset_index()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 4))
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=grouped, x='Clusters', y='Labels', size='Lable', color='orchid')
for h in ax.legend_.legendHandles:
    h.set_color('orchid')  # the default color in the sizes legends is black
ax.margins(x=0.01) # less whitespace
# set the legend outside
ax.legend(handles=ax.legend_.legendHandles, title='Counts:', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image: scatterplot with sizes]

You could also try the approach from [How to make jitterplot on matplolib python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229586/how-to-make-jitterplot-on-matplolib-python), optionally using different jitter offsets in x and y direction. With your data it could look as follows:

```
def jitter_dots(dots):
    offsets = dots.get_offsets()
    jittered_offsets = offsets
    jittered_offsets[:, 0] += np.random.uniform(-0.3, 0.3, offsets.shape[0]) # x
    jittered_offsets[:, 1] += np.random.uniform(-0.3, 0.3, offsets.shape[0]) # y
    dots.set_offsets(jittered_offsets)

ax = sns.scatterplot(data=stacked, x='Clusters', y='Labels')
jitter_dots(ax.collections[0])
```

[image: scatterplot with jitter]

Here is how it could look like with 8 different colors, alternating per cluster:

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=stacked, x='Clusters', y='Labels',
                     hue=stacked['Clusters'] % 8, palette='Dark2', legend=False)
jitter_dots(ax.collections[0])
ax.margins(x=0.02)
sns.despine()
```

[image: scatterplot with colors per column]

Comment: i appreacite your answer. With regards to your first answer, am not looking for histogram.  And with respect to the second one, i dont have to show counts explicitly. I need to draw a simple in scatter plot which just describe each clusters with dots equals to the number of amount labels it has.

Comment: it seems to be working as what i want , could you also tell me, how we can change the color of dots for each cluster

Comment: Yes, I have added "hue='Clusters' " and now it gives me exactly what i want.  thanks man

Comment: Nice trick at the end with the modulo hues.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can use a [**`swarmplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) (or the similar [**`stripplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html)):

```py
sns.swarmplot(data=stacked, x='Clusters', y='Labels')
```

[image: swarm plot]

Comment: here i have posted the demo dict.  But in real i have dictionary where each cluster cotains at least 40 labels. I have tried to use swarmplot or stripplot there already.  But still it didnot show all points